# How to custom jqgrid search dialog

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

i'm starter in jqGrid. i have 4 feild , `Id`,`Name`,`Date` and `Age`. i Want when user click in icon search and appear search box when select `Date` item for search Now Appear one textBox for user enter your date, but i want Appear two textBox for user enter `FromDate` and `ToDate`.like this form
[image]

please help me. thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User beforeShowForm event and add whatever you want like this..

```
beforeShowForm: function (form) {

            $("#Location").empty();
            $("#Location").append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
            $("#Area").empty();
            $("#Area").append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
        }
```